# I get all the time a message "contained a virus and was deleted" whenever I try to download a file

Tags: virus, trojan

I have some virus on my system. when ever I try to download a file (no matter which one) I get a message: "file contained a virus and was deleted". I looked over the internet and saw that some say to use AVG 2013, some say spybot search & destroy and other use some way with safe mode.

I tried to scan using avg 2013 and it found some trojan that connected to explorer.exe and coudln't delete.

I tried search & destroy and also didn't help.

About the last thing I want you to say if this is the right way to do it. I'm afraid that I'll delete something from the registry that will harm my computer.
Another thing I don't understand wich proccess I need to kill from the taskbar???

What do u think about all of this? Do you know some other way to deal with this virus/trojan?

p.s I also saw some posts here about it but they didn't help me...

Comment: have you tried running the virus scans in safe mode ?

Comment: No, Will the AVG scan work in safe mode?

Comment: there should be an option to do that, which version of windows are you running ?

Comment: windows 7 I don't know wich one of them..

Comment: just open the antivirus when you boot into safe mode, see this link http://www.avg.com/us-en/faq.num-5192

Comment: I recommend this tool. It worked for me. I am a user and not affiliated with this company. http://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/free-tools/virus-removal-tool.aspx

Comment: The explorer detection sounds like a false positive

Comment: Maybe @Karan will provide you with some insight from on-high.  Seems to know everything.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with viruses in explorer.exe. I do know that if you have virus at that level it is going to be very hard to fully remove it. Explorer.exe is the viewer for your desktop, taskbar and Windows Explorer. Since the virus is infecting that area of windows, I would expect it to be in many system processes. If this is the case your best bet is to reformat.  The level at which it takes to remove remove viruses of this kind often require programs like Combo Fix which can require some experience and plenty of time.